# What about the Users Python API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-openid

Add me to the list of people confused by all this: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect.  I currently use the Python Users API in an AppEngine application running at https://www.stackmonkey.com/.  I build the login URL for my login button like this:

```
login_url = users.create_login_url(federated_identity='gmail.com', dest_url=dest_url)
self.redirect(login_url)
```

The Users API manages my user DB for me.  I'm able to pull the current user's session with this code:

```
current_user = users.get_current_user()
```

Given the complete lack of information on the topic anywhere I've looked on Google's pages, I'm wondering if anyone has any information on whether the Users API can be made to work with the suggested migrations, or if Google is going to update the Users API to support the new authentication methods they suggest?

At least I have some time on this, but I'm really not looking forward to reimplementing an entire auth system in my app.

Small update, I've tried creating a sample application running at kordtest2.appspot.com which is returning a 400:

```
Error: Bad Request

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.
```

The code used for that sample app is cut and pasted from the Python getting started guide on their site (I can't post another link with this account).

Comment: Downvoted. Appreciate the support, people.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it appears to be when I was logged into multiple GMAIL/GOOGLE accounts at the same time. When I logged out of all of them except one, that one worked fine with my code, based on the sample Python code.